# How do I get Rails to accept decimals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating some table data in a Rails-React application.

I had creating this piece of data here in console:

```
2.3.3 :024 > Crop.create date: Date.today, cropname: 'Radishes', ismetric: false, bagspackaged: '20', unitweight: '0.5', totalweight: '10'
```

Today I realized that Rails did not accept the 0.5 decimal for unitweight and no matter how I try to update it in console, it does not save.

This is my schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171004224716) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "crops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "date"
    t.string "cropname"
    t.boolean "ismetric"
    t.integer "bagspackaged"
    t.integer "unitweight"
    t.integer "totalweight"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: You have `unitweight` defined as an integer. Not sure what you expect by assigning 0.5 to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid rolling back your crops table, it would just be more work. It is up to you.

I would just do:

```
rails g migration ChangeUnitweightToFloat
```

Inside that file I would configure like so:

```
class ChangeUnitweightToFloat < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :crops, :unitweight, :float
  end
end
```

With these two steps, you should be go to go.
For future reference, please keep in mind that if you want to work with decimals, it will either be a t.decimal or t.float.

Answer (score 4):

Two issues here

- First you have given the data type `integer` to `unitweight` and `totalweight`, while you should have given it `decimal` or `float` in order to accept and store fractions. `decimal` data type with precision is better as it will give you more accurate result as stated below in the comments' section. 
  when you use `decimal` you can control it by The precision which is total number of digits in a number, whereas scale is number of digits following the decimal point.

  here is an example

  `add_column :tickets, :price, :decimal, precision: 5, scale: 2`

  this will allow you to store decimal numbers like these 60.00, 80.99 and 100.00
- Second you are passing `string` to `integer`, it is not a problem because rails will convert it to `integer` as long as it is a valid `integer` otherwise it will be `0`. But generally it is not a good practice.

Comment: `decimal` with a precision specified is preferable to `float`.

Comment: @tadman sure it is I just giving him both options but you are right I should have said that. since you have said no need to re-write it again.

Comment: Absolutely, no problem with options. People just get burned all the time by pure floats when `0.5` comes out as `0.499999994812`.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a decimal, it's a string. Don't put quotes around your numeric literals.

```
Crop.create(
  date: Date.today,
  cropname: 'Radishes',
  ismetric: false,
  bagspackaged: 20,
  unitweight: 0.5,
  totalweight: 10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `decimal` (or `float`) type field instead of an integer:

```
create_table "crops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.decimal "unitweight"
end
```

and then don't use quotes around the value:

```
2.3.3 :024 > Crop.create date: Date.today, cropname: 'Radishes', ismetric: false, bagspackaged: '20', unitweight: 0.5, totalweight: '10'
```

Comment: Do I need to rollback my initial migration?

Comment: You could either rollback or create another migration that would remove that column remove_column and then and the new column with add_column